# How to vectorize pandas calculation involving custom grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a large dataframe holding mapping users (index) to counts of items (columns):

```
users_items = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0],      # user 0
                                     [1, 0, 0, 0],      # user 1
                                     [5, 0, 0, 9],      # user 2
                                     [0, 3, 5, 0],      # user 3
                                     [0, 2, 2, 0],      # user 4
                                     [7, 0, 0, 1],      # user 5
                                     [3, 5, 0, 4]]),    # user 6
                           columns=list('ABCD'))
```

For each user, I want to find all the users that have non-zero counts for at least the same items and sum their counts. So for user 1, this would be users 1, 2, 5 and 6 and the sum of the counts equals `[16, 5, 0, 14]`. This can be used to suggest new items to users based on the items that "similar" users got.

This naive implementation uses a signature as a regular expression to filter out the relevant rows and a for loop to loop over all signatures:

```
def create_signature(request_counts):
    return ''.join('x' if count else '.' for count in request_counts)

users_items['signature'] = users_items.apply(create_signature, axis=1).astype('category')

current_items = users_items.groupby('signature').sum()

similar_items = pd.DataFrame(index=current_items.index,
                             columns=current_items.columns)

for signature in current_items.index:
    row = current_items.filter(regex=signature, axis='index').sum()
    similar_items.loc[signature] = row
```

The result is:

```
            A  B  C   D
signature              
.xx.        0  6  8   0
x...       16  5  0  14
x..x       15  5  0  14
xx.x        3  5  0   4
```

This works fine, but it is too slow for the actual data set which consists of 100k users and some 600 items. Generating the signatures takes only 10 seconds, but looping over all (40k) signatures takes several hours.

Vectorizing the loop should offer a huge performance boost, but my experience with Pandas is limited so I'm not sure how to go about it. It is even possible to vectorize this type of calculation? Perhaps using masks?

Comment: Why are there only 4 signatures for the example? Do you need other combinations like .x..,.xxx,x.xx etc? Why are these 4 chosen?

Comment: @Allen The set of signatures simply result from whatever data happens to be in the users_items dataframe. Not all possible signatures will occur.

Comment: so 'x...' should be the sum of all rows of which it is a subset of it's signature

Comment: Do you need a result for each row? And how is the sum calculated? Is it the sum of all values in the same column, but only **under** the row we are looking at, or does it include all rows, including the row we are looking at?

Comment: @ChuckM Yes, I need a result for each row. The sum includes all rows for which the (signature) regex matches the signature; see the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `string` as signature, you can use a `frozenset`

```
def create_signature(request_counts):
    return frozenset(request_counts[request_counts != 0].index)
```

an alternative is

```
def create_signature(request_counts):
    return frozenset(request_counts.replace({0: None}).dropna().index)
```

I don't have a dataset large enough to see whether one is faster than the other.

If you have duplicate columns, insert a call to `reset_index()` before the `.index`

This allows you to vectorise your filter in the end

```
for signature in current_items.index:
    row = current_items[signature <= current_items.index].sum()
    similar_items.loc[signature] = row
```

results in

```
signature                   A   B   C   D
frozenset({'B', 'C'})       0   6   8   0
frozenset({'A'})            16  5   0   14
frozenset({'A', 'D'})       15  5   0   14
frozenset({'B', 'A', 'D'})  3   5   0   4
```

Comment: I would have thought that using frozensets (I was thinking of a bit arrays myself) instead of strings for the signatures would be much faster. Unfortunately, generating the frozenset signatures takes much longer (2+ minutes versus 10 seconds). That said, using fronzesets the loop will take only 6 hours instead of 8, so there's a definite improvement here. However, I think only vectorizing the for loop will be able to speed up this operation enough.

Comment: does the for-loop still takes as long as the string one, because I would expect the `set` comparisons to be faster than the `regex`. Bit arrays might be faster still

Comment: I did after I submitted my comment. I've updated it now.

Comment: Using the **indices** of the columns instead of their names in the frozenset makes the generation of the signatures pretty much instant and the for loop is also sped up.